# Implementation of Python code which uses Tensorflow library into HTML?

Tags: javascript, python, html, tensorflow, keras

Machine learning beginner here. I've been following the tensorflow text classification tutorial. I have code which uses a trained keras model to classify movie reviews based on user inputted text.

My main question is this: How do I integrate this code into html so that I can create a website which takes in user text and classifies it using the python code?

I'm unfamiliar with tensorflow.js, and converting the model over doesn't transfer the keras dataset.

Is there some web framework which can support the tensorflow library, or any library for that matter? Or should I give up on this endeavor and just transfer the model into tensorflow.js?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use tensorflow as your machine learning package and a web framework like flask or django as your web framework, you can then call your machine learning models based on your html input.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the question. There is a Python version of Tensorflow, would that not be easier? It sounds like there are a few separate questions here. These might be "how do I build a website with an API that runs my backend code?" and "how do I convert my Keras model to Tensorflow?" (and "can I do both of those in one step using some wizardry?" To which the answer is probably no). Maybe you can make your question a bit more specific?

Comment: If you want to do such a thing, I advise you to follow a few courses on web development and architecture so that you get a better understanding of how web works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Flask](https://www.fullstackpython.com/flask.html) to make a Web App that gets the data via a Form POST and do you thing with the tensorflow and display the results in another Page.

Something Like

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/classify', methods=['POST'])
def classify():
    text = request.form['name_of_text_input_in_index.html']
    # Call your tensorflow function with the text
    result = classify_with_tensorflow(text)
    return render_template('result.html', result = result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

Display the results with formatting on a Jinja Template

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Flask but here as you mentioned there has to be some user input for classification using code and your page will also return some output to user, the methods used should be "GET" and "POST".
Please refer to code snippet below.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import render_template, url_for, flash, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['user'] !='username' or request.form['password'] != 'password':
            error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('my_form_post'))
    return render_template("login.html", error=error)
```